# hash_equals() alternative for PHP 5.5.9

Tags: php, web

My webhost doesn't allow usage of PHP 5.5.9 and I need to use the hash_equals() function.

Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: The user contributed note by `asphp at dsgml dot com` on the [hash_equals() PHP Docs page](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) provides code that can be used with earlier versions of PHP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
if(!function_exists('hash_equals')) {
  function hash_equals($str1, $str2) {
    if(strlen($str1) != strlen($str2)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      $res = $str1 ^ $str2;
      $ret = 0;
      for($i = strlen($res) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) $ret |= ord($res[$i]);
      return !$ret;
    }
  }
}
```

Code from: asphp at dsgml dot com

Copied from the [PHP comments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php#115635).

Comment: Maybe you want to say from where you have this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php#115635

Comment: Remember to cite [where you copied the code from](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php#115635), unless you are the original author.

Comment: Sure, sorry for that. I changed comment and added information where user can see original post.

Comment: @Erminesoft Shouldn't it be `if(function_exists)` (without !)? Seems to me now it says, if function hash_equals does **not** exists, do hash_equals, else...

Comment: The comment is removed from PHP site. Is the function actually correct?